# File structures of Cassandra and how to specify its directory in Cassandra Cluster Manager (CCM)?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I have successfully installed Cassandra-2.0.9 following [the DATASTAX document](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html?) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. For a quick test of cluster on local machine, I then installed the [Cassandra Cluster Manager (CCM) tool](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ccm-a-development-tool-for-creating-local-cassandra-clusters).

To create a cluster, a command like `ccm create --cassandra-dir *** --nodes 3 --start test` is issued, which is expected to set up and start a 3-node cluster named "test". **However, I am not sure what the cassandra-directory is under my current installation.**

**My questions:**

> 1. What `cassandra-dir` should be specified?
> 2. How are the Cassandra files organized? As a novice of Ubuntu, I am quite confused about the files scattered in different directories.

**P.S.:** The command `dpkg -L cassandra` gives the following list of Cassandra-related files. If you need more information, please free feel to ask. Thanks.

```
/.
/var
/var/lib
/var/lib/cassandra
/var/log
/var/log/cassandra
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/sstablesplit
/usr/bin/sstablelevelreset
/usr/bin/cassandra-shuffle
/usr/bin/sstable2json
/usr/bin/json2sstable
/usr/bin/cassandra-cli
/usr/bin/nodetool
/usr/bin/sstablekeys
/usr/bin/cqlsh
/usr/bin/cassandra-stress
/usr/bin/token-generator
/usr/bin/sstableloader
/usr/bin/sstablescrub
/usr/bin/sstableupgrade
/usr/bin/sstablemetadata
/usr/share
/usr/share/cassandra
/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.9.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.0.9.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-internal-only-0.3.3.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-15.0.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-python-internal-only-0.9.1.zip
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar
/usr/share/cassandra/cassandra.in.sh
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/cassandra
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/CHANGES.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/antlr-3.2.txt
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/netty-3.5.9.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/log4j-1.2.16.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/thrift-python-0.9.1.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/snakeyaml-1.11.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/super-csv-2.1.0.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.txt
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/metrics-core-2.2.0.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/commons-lang3-3.1.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/jline-1.0.txt
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/thrift-server-0.3.3.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/commons-cli-1.1.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/json-simple-1.1.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/commons-codec-1.2.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/jbcrypt-0.3m.txt
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/guava-15.0.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/disruptor-3.0.1.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/libthrift-0.9.1.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/cql-1.4.0.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/reporter-config-2.1.0.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/netty-3.6.6.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/slf4j-api-1.7.2.txt
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/compress-lzf-0.8.4.txt
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.txt
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/snaptree-0.1.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/lz4-1.2.0.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/snappy-java-1.0.5.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/licenses/jamm-0.2.5.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/copyright
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/README.asc
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/TODO
/usr/share/doc/cassandra/NEWS.txt.gz
/usr/share/pyshared
/usr/share/pyshared/cassandra_pylib-0.0.0.egg-info
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/helptopics.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/saferscanner.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/formatting.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/pylexotron.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/util.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/__init__.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/tfactory.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/displaying.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/tracing.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/wcwidth.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/cqlhandling.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/cql3handling.py
/usr/share/pyshared/cqlshlib/ssl.py
/usr/share/python-support
/usr/share/python-support/cassandra.public
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/cassandra
/etc
/etc/cassandra
/etc/cassandra/commitlog_archiving.properties
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-topology.yaml
/etc/cassandra/log4j-server.properties
/etc/cassandra/triggers
/etc/cassandra/triggers/README.txt
/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-topology.properties
/etc/cassandra/log4j-tools.properties
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh
/etc/security
/etc/security/limits.d
/etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/cassandra
/etc/sysctl.d
/etc/sysctl.d/cassandra.conf
/etc/default
/etc/default/cassandra
/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCM doesn't use binary Cassandra installs, it always builds from source (it's originally a dev tool).

`--cassandra-dir` is when you want to point it at an existing source directory (typically, when you're hacking on Cassandra and want to try your modified version).

Otherwise, you can simply give it a Cassandra version and it will download and compile the sources for you:

```
ccm create my_cluster_name -v 2.0.9
```

I don't know if you've seen it already, but the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) contains useful information.

Comment: Thanks. Whether the Cassandra automatically installed by CCM (using `cassandra-version`) is self-contained and fully functioning? In other words, is CCM an easy (by-product) installation of Cassandra, compared to [this way](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html?)?

Comment: Yes, CCM is an easy way to install for testing only. For a production-grade installation, follow the page you linked.

Comment: Can CCM be installed and used in Windows? And how to?

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but yes. You need to install Java, Python, and then you should be able to run the `ccm` script from a terminal (run `set execution-policy = unrestricted` before launching the script).